# Database Query with 3 Months Current Year and Previous Year

Tags: oracle, date

Hope am not over thinking this...

I am currently looking for any pointers on this. I have a table/view

```
|Cust_ID | CName | Inv_Date   | Sales
|01A     | A     | 2/7/2006   | 20
|02A     | B     | 2/7/2006   | 10
|01A     | A     | 11/5/2005  | 15
```

Each customer has very many invoices on various dates
I would then like to extract each customer with **sales** for

- Three (months) of the current year (e.g. 2006). This is 3 months prior to today's date.

  ```
  Inv_Date >= add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'month'), -3)
  and Inv_Date <= add_months(last_day(sysdate), -1)
  ```

  The **same** three (3) months of the previous year (2005)?!

Would assume something like

```
|Cust_ID | CName | CY_Sum_Sales | PY_Sum_Sales
|01A     | A     | 20           | 15
|02A     | B     | 0            | 0
```

Assuming 'sysdate' is 1/8/2008. The following is my trial

```
select Customer_No, Customer_Name,
   TO_CHAR(SUM(Sales_Colmn), 'fm999G999G999G999G999D0') as "TYear_Sale",
    
 TO_CHAR((SELECT SUM(Sales_Colmn) from cust_table CL
 where CL.invoice_date BETWEEN add_months(trunc(to_date('&From_Dt', 'DD/MM/YYYY'), 'mm'), -(3 + 12)) --15 months
   and add_months(trunc(to_date('&To_Dt', 'DD/MM/YYYY'), 'mm'), -(1 + 12)) --13 months) 
   and Customer_No = CL.Customer_No), 'fm999G999G999G999G999D0') as "LYear_Sale"
from cust_table
where invoice_date BETWEEN add_months(trunc(to_date('&From_Dt', 'DD/MM/YYYY'), 'mm'), -3) --3 months
  and add_months(trunc(to_date('&To_Dt', 'DD/MM/YYYY'), 'mm'), -1) --1 months)
 GROUP BY Customer_No, Customer_Name
 ORDER BY 3
```

But it takes too long to run. Must be doing something wrong

Comment: MySQL is not an Oracle and Oracle is not MySQL. Please, check tag description and remove either one.

Comment: Also please show your current attempt and describe what is wrong with it

Comment: What is your `Inv_Date` data type?? It looks like `char` or some string data type. If so, you should never store dates as strings, you should use the date/datetime data types

Comment: @nacho it is date

Answer (score 1):

Functions (`add_months`, `sysdate`) you use suggest this is Oracle.

As you want to go back to same months previous year, you just have to add (OK, *subtract*) another 12 months. Something like this:

```
SQL> select trunc(sysdate) c_today,
  2         trunc(sysdate, 'mm') c_trunc_today,
  3         --
  4         add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'mm'), -3) c_3_months_ago,
  5         add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'mm'), -1) c_1_month_ago,
  6         --
  7         add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'mm'), -(3 + 12)) c_15_months_ago,
  8         add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'mm'), -(1 + 12)) c_13_months_ago
  9  from dual;                                    ^^
                                                   this!
C_TODAY    C_TRUNC_TO C_3_MONTHS C_1_MONTH_ C_15_MONTH C_13_MONTH
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
03.11.2021 01.11.2021 01.08.2021 01.10.2021 01.08.2020 01.10.2020
                      --------------------- =====================
                      this year             previous year, same months

SQL>
```

Comment: Have added a trial following your reply @Littlefoot